# Formtastic semantic_form_for undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, formtastic

I am trying to set up a form using Formtastic which has a drop down. My Ruby app works fine with the following form:

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content, "Add a Country to your carrier" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 8 %>
  </p>
  <p><%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path(:parent_id => @london_message) %></p>
<% end %>
```

When I change `form_for` to `semantic_form_for` it is throwing an 'undefined method' error. Can anyone explain the different between these two methods and why `semantic_form_for` is not working?

Comment: A little more context around the error message would help, as it usually indicates what the target of the undefined method is...

Comment: Can you confirm that "formtastic" is in your Gemfile and that you've run `bundle` (and restarted your rails server?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I had added 'formtastic' to my Gemfile and run  `bundle install` but I have not restarted my rails server. Silly mistake, thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`form_for` and `semantic_form_for` are two separate form builders. They have a lot of similarities, but the Formtastic version allows you to use a lot of shorthand methods to avoid repeating a lot of boilerplate.

If `semantic_form_for` is throwing 'undefined method', it sounds like Formtastic is not being loaded correctly. If you go into the Rails console and type `Formtastic`, it should return "Formtastic". If you get "Uninitialized Constant" instead, then the problem is definitely somewhere in the gem loading process.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the differences. The rails console showed me that Formtastic was installed but I had not restarted the rails server. semantic_from_for is now working fine.